# How to get index of matched element from json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var formRenderData = [{
  "type": "checkbox-group",
  "label": "Checkbox Group",
  "className": "checkbox-group",
  "name": "checkbox-group-1479370460494",
  "values": [{
    "label": "Option 1",
    "value": "option-1",
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "label": "Option 2",
    "value": "option-2"
  }, {
    "label": "Option 3",
    "value": "option-3"
  }]
}, {
  "type": "paragraph",
  "subtype": "p",
  "label": "Paragraph",
  "className": "paragraph"
}];
```

I am using grep to match object.

```
var InputName = 'checkbox-group-1479370460494';
var InputType = 'checkbox-group';

var returnedIndex = $.grep(formRenderData, function(element, index){
    if(( (element.name == InputName) || (element.label == InputName)|| (element.name == InputName.substr(0,InputName.length - 2)) ) && element.type == InputType){
        return index;
    }
});

console.log(returnedIndex);
```

Comment: Use some other form of loop rather than `$.grep()`? The `$.grep()` function returns an array of matched items. You could use `.map()` to return the matched item(s) with an added `index` property. By the way, there's no JSON in your question, and [no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: can i use $.map( formRenderData, function( element, index ) {
  // Do something
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jQuery.grep` filters an array, returning a list of the items that satisfied the filter function while leaving the original array untouched. (See [the jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/).)

I'm not sure why you wanted to access the index; I assume you wanted access to the original object that satisfied the filter. This could be accomplished by returning `true` from your filter function, and then looping through the matches array afterwards.

```js
var InputName = 'checkbox-group-1479370460494';
var InputType = 'checkbox-group';
var formRenderData = [{"type": "checkbox-group","label": "Checkbox Group","className": "checkbox-group","name": "checkbox-group-1479370460494","values": [{"label": "Option 1","value": "option-1","selected": true},{"label": "Option 2","value": "option-2"},{"label": "Option 3","value": "option-3"}]},{"type": "paragraph","subtype": "p","label": "Paragraph","className": "paragraph"}]

var matches = $.grep(formRenderData, function(element, index){
    if(( (element.name == InputName) || (element.label == InputName)|| (element.name == InputName.substr(0,InputName.length - 2)) ) && element.type == InputType){
        return true
    }
});

console.log(matches); // [Array]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```